# JSQMessagesViewController message view error

Tags: xcode, unrecognized-selector, jsqmessagesviewcontroller, invalidargumentexception

I have an app that is error-free when I run in **Debug** mode, but when I run it in **Release** mode, I get this error when the message view tries to display messages:

```
2016-09-14 16:17:31.305 MyApp[70800:1072070] -[_TtCs19_NSContiguousString messageHash]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa4eb461db0
2016-09-14 16:17:31.318 MyApp[70800:1072070] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtCs19_NSContiguousString messageHash]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa4eb461db0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108979d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a866deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108982d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088c8cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088c88a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   JSQMessagesViewController           0x0000000108549e7c -[JSQMessagesBubblesSizeCalculator messageBubbleSizeForMessageData:atIndexPath:withLayout:] + 130
    6   JSQMessagesViewController           0x000000010854f960 -[JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout messageBubbleSizeForItemAtIndexPath:] + 232
    7   JSQMessagesViewController           0x000000010854faec -[JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout jsq_configureMessageCellLayoutAttributes:] + 97
    8   JSQMessagesViewController           0x000000010854ed86 __73-[JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]_block_invoke + 92
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088b4afd __53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 77
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088b49a6 -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 166
    11  JSQMessagesViewController           0x000000010854ecf5 -[JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:] + 1211
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000109b8658a __45-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]_block_invoke + 144
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000109b85fd7 -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 3067
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000109b3253a -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 199
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010936d980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010df80c00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010df7508e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010df74f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010df693c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010df97086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010df977f8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010889ec37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010889eba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088947fb __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088940f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bb8fad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    27  UIKit                               0x00000001092b2f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    28  MyApp                             0x0000000106f69e6d main + 125
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b37192d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am not sure why this is the case only in **Release mode**, but does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is in relation to the message hash of the message. Make sure that you have your message object set up correctly. In that it adheres to the

> `JSQMessageData` protocol